# Twitter bootstrap bigger glyphicons.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to use the twitter bootstrap and adjust there size to be bigger ?
I have tried this so far with no luck.
    glyphicon.myclass {height: 100px; width: 100px;}

Thank you.

Comment: Bootstrap 3.0 or 2.3.x?

Comment: For bootstrap 2, please see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311231/font-awesome-vs-glyphyicons-in-twitter-bootstrap/17319709#17319709

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's Bootstrap 3, then try increasing the font-size if it applies to the element. Example below.

```
glyphicon.myclass {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 2** icons are applied as backgrounds, so no. Also, they're an image sprite, so resizing the sprite image would require you to adjust every CSS position statement.

**Bootstrap 3** icons are a font, so yes.

```
.glyphicon.smaller {font-size: 8px;}
.glyphicon.bigger {font-size: 30px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Glyphicons use the `font-size` of their container. So you can increase the font-size as suggested by others, or use a container with larger font..

```
<h1><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></i></h1>
```

http://bootply.com/98574

Comment: It's worth noting that, while this works nicely, it encourages non-semantic markup. Headings, for example, should not be used to style icons and text, but to structure the document logically.

Comment: Although implemantation is easy, w3c validator gives `Empty heading` warning for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739224/empty-heading-warning-on-html5-validation