# Empty heading warning on HTML5 validation

Tags: html, wordpress, validation, syntax-error

I try to validate my HTML code and I have found this warning: Empty heading. [See here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.codetocode-developments.com/battle/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)

Obviously the heading is not empty. The content of the `<h3></h3>` is generated, in WordPress, by `the_title()` function. So, I don't understand why is this happen.. Somebody can explain me what is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, the HTML is valid. It passes the W3C check, so you don't need to worry *too* much.

With that said, your code *is* misusing HTML syntax. The "empty heading" warning means that you have a heading tag (`<hN>`) that doesn't have any content associated with it. Heading tags are intended to mean "this is what this bit of content is about". [As the HTML5 spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/h3.html):

> The `h1` through `h6` elements are headings for the sections with which they are associated.

You are instead using the `h3` tag as a formatting instruction. It has no content associated; the words are not actually the header for any content. This is misusing the semantics of the tag.

Does this matter? Probably not, though software which relies on the semantics of HTML rather than the appearance (e.g. screenreaders) might find it tricky. I'm not sure about how Wordpress works -- it might be very difficult to fix anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Your are right it would be an span or simply p tag, there is no reason for use heading tag.

Comment: I regularly check my site against the validation checker, it passes HTML5 but recently got the empty header warnings. The validation checker is just a guide, and rightly so as it is bad practice of me to use <h3> instead of a styled <p> tag. Just goes to show that its updated regularly.

Comment: beware your <h> tag is not empty because of wordpress - the_title() is a function written in PHP - a server side language that processes instructions and THEN delivers the html, looking at your code you have an <h1> that is filled by the "the_title()" and then an empty left over <h2> tag