# HTML5 valid way to populate text tags with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

So I'm just checking that my website is HTML5 valid, and I have an unusual issue.

When I validate it using the w3's validator tool:
http://validator.w3.org

I'm warned that the heading tags are empty in some cases. This is where I populate them using Javascript after page load - so I can give them an animation effect.

Should I be using a span element rather than a `<h2>`? Or is there an alternative/should I be ignoring this warning - although I want the entire website to be HTML5 valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question: [Empty heading warning on HTML5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739224/empty-heading-warning-on-html5-validation)

**In Short:** you're fine. If you have dynamically generated text for your headers the w3 validator will throw a *warning*, but not an *error*.

Comment: Wouldn't it possibly pass with a simple `&nbsp;` ??

Comment: Headings semantically are intended to be titles for sections (a headline for an article, for example).  Those boxes aren't really headings, so yes, either a <div> or a <span> element would be more appropriate.