# How Do I Make Glyphicons Bigger? (Change Size?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I would like to make the globe glyphicon bigger so that it covers up a large portion of the page (it's a vector image). It's not in a button or anything; it's just alone. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bigger Glyphicons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478365/bigger-glyphicons)

Answer (score 394, accepted):

Increase the font-size of `glyphicon` to increase all icons size.

```
.glyphicon {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

To target only one icon,

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-globe {
    font-size: 75px;
}
```

Comment: `text-center` on the div.

Comment: to make the glyphicon larger "on demand" use .glyphicon.larger {
    font-size: 150%;
}

Comment: What about making it thinner?

Comment: I had to add `!important;` to the font size to override the boostrap CSS.

Answer (score 147):

Fontawesome has a perfect solution to this.

I implemented the same. just on your main .css file add this

```
.gi-2x{font-size: 2em;}
.gi-3x{font-size: 3em;}
.gi-4x{font-size: 4em;}
.gi-5x{font-size: 5em;}
```

In your example you just have to do this.

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe gi-5x"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! You can also use fractional amounts like 1.5em.

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer and shows a generic solution to a recurring problem.

Answer (score 75):

If you are using bootstrap and font-awesome then it is easy, no need to write a single line of new code, just add fa-Nx, as big you want, [See the  demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rKMEZ/293/)

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe fa-lg"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe fa-2x"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe fa-3x"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe fa-4x"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe fa-5x"></span>
```

Comment: Glyphicons and Font-Awesome join forces!

Comment: I am not in favour of combining FA and Glyphicons. See below answer on how to upsize the glyphicon using inline style or via a css class above. Or for a pure FA solution use -> fa fa-globe fa-2x ( v4.x)

Comment: MarcoZen: anyway by next version of bootstrap 4 Glyphicons are going to be removed, many of us earlier were using together.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, and basically you can also use inline style:

```
<span style="font-size: 15px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
```

Answer (score 11):

try to use heading, no need extra css

```
<h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></h1>
```

Comment: You can do this, but it doesn't give you a fine level of control the way a little bit of CSS would.

Comment: Using headers because of their effect on font-size is an anti-pattern.  A user navigating your site by keyboard would be sent straight to your icon as the screen reader assumes it signifies a title/heading for the most important content on the page.

Answer (score 10):

For ex ..
add class:

btn-lg - LARGE

btn-sm - SMALL

btn-xs - Very small

```
<button type=button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden=true></span> Star
</button> 

<button type=button class="btn btn-default">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden=true></span>Star
</button>

 <button type=button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden=true></span> Star
</button> 

<button type=button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden=true></span> Star
</button>
```

Ref link Bootstrap  : [Glyphicons Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels)

Comment: The question regarded the images, not the images as buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I've used bootstrap header classes ("h1", "h2", etc.) for this. This way you get all the style benefits without using the actual tags. Here is an example:

`<div class="h3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>`